# Angular2 Style encapsulation not working

Tags: angular, sass

One of the features I enjoy most about `ng2` has been that when working with larger applications, it [should be guaranteed](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) that styles should not conflict between different components in the app.

However, in our app it is not working correctly. Here is an example component the way we have been creating them:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-name',
    template: require('./componentName.html'),
    styles: [require('./componentName.scss').toString()],
    providers: [...]
})
```

There have been style conflicts in the app, which has lead to having to namespace the scss files per component:

```
component-name {
    a { }
    p { }
    ...
}
```

Is there something about how the component is instantiated that we're doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: did you compiled your SCSS to CSS?

Comment: if it is really so, it's a bug, unless you use encapsulation: `ViewEncapsulation.None`